# Screenshot program/tool that captures a specific monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screenshot

I'm struggling to find a screenshot program or tool that will capture a fullscreen screenshot on a specific display. There is many that give the option to capture a specific window, an area of the screen or all 3 of my monitors, but I would like to be able to screenshot just 1 monitor.

Any help towards finding a program or method to do what I want to do would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at *maim*? "-x, --xdisplay=hostname:number.screen_number"

Comment: Seems to do what I want, but I have no idea how it works. I've tried maim -x :0.1 screenshot.png
Maim encountered an error:
Error: Failed to open X display: :0.1

Comment: Have you tried Kazam? If I select Screenshot, Fullscreen and move the Kazam window to my desired monitor it grabs the full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I use the built-in Screenshot-Function: activate with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>-key combination, then drag open a Capturing-Frame with Left-Mouse-Button, release to capture. Or for that Matter there's a builtin Screencapture-Video Function too: The Hotkey can be configured in the Systemsetting:Devices:Keyboard as it is not assigned by Default.
[image: screenshot]